# What is the proper way of searching for a reference whose type is unknown?

Tags: citations, cross-referencing

In the article, *Stability of quantum motion in chaotic and regular systems*, Physical Review A, 30, 1610 (1984), in the reference section these two references given:

> [11]M. V. Berry, in Chaotic Behaoior of Deterministic Systeins, Vol. 36 of
>   Les Houches Summer School Proceedings, edited by G. Iooss, R. H. G.
>   Helleman, and R. Stora (North- Holland, Amsterdam, 1983).

and

> [13]A. Peres, in Quantum Chaos, edited by G. Casati and J. Ford (Plenum,
>   New York, 1984), and references therein.

However, when I search for these two publications, for the first one, I can only a single volume - 16th - and the for the latter one none at all.

It is clear from the title that the first publication is a Proceeding of some summer school held, but the the second one, I cannot even speculate what it is from the way it is referenced ("in ..."); a book, an article, etc.

**Question:**

First my second question: what type of publication the second reference references ?

Secondly my first question: what is the proper way of searching such documents.

Comment: Plenum publishes books.

Comment: You could start with a reference librarian or maybe email the authors or editors or a list server.

Comment: [MathSciNet turned up the first one](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=724465).

Comment: North-Holland is/was a journal publisher. If not still independent, it likely is part of Elsivier. Librarians to the rescue!